# Avoid row was cut by GROUP_CONCAT error on insert without changing group_concat_max_len

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an insert that uses a GROUP_CONCAT.  In certain scenarios, the insert fails with Row XX was cut by GROUP_CONCAT.  I understand why it fails but I'm looking for a way to have it not error out since the insert column is already smaller than the group_concat_max_len.  I don't want to increase group_concat_max_len.

```
drop table if exists a;
create table a (x varchar(10), c int);

drop table if exists b;
create table b (x varchar(10));

insert into b values ('abcdefgh');
insert into b values ('ijklmnop');

-- contrived example to show that insert column size varchar(10) < 15
set session group_concat_max_len = 15;

insert into a select group_concat(x separator ', '), count(*) from b;
```

This insert produces the error `Row 2 was cut by GROUP_CONCAT()`.

I'll try to provide a few clarifications -

1. The data in table b is unknown.  There is no way to say set group_concat_max_len to a value greater than 18.
2. I do know the insert column size.
3. Why group_concat 4 GB of data when you want the first x characters?
4. When the concatenated string is longer than 10 chars, it should insert the first 10 characters.

Thanks.

Comment: What would you want the query to do?, the concatenation is longer than 10 chars

Comment: What about using `SUBSTRING()` to cut it down to the length of the target column?

Comment: Why don't you want to set `group_concat_max_len` to an appropriate length?  I don't know much about MySQL, but I think it always fails if  not set to be long enough.

Comment: @VMai, I couldn't get string functions to work and they produce the same exception.

Comment: "yes, concat" doesn't seem like an answer though

Comment: Again, why don't you want to set `group_concat_max_len`?  You could create a running total for string length and limit the `GROUP_CONCAT()` query based on that length, but why?

Comment: @GoatCO, good question, I added clarification to the question.

Comment: Look, just explain to us what your query should insert when the concatenated string is longer than 10 chars

Comment: @Lamak, sorry, the first 10 characters.

Answer (score 4):

Your example `GROUP_CONCAT` is probably cooking up this value:

```
 abcdefgh, ijklmnop
```

That is 18 characters long, including the separator.

Can you try something like this?

```
set session group_concat_max_len = 4096;
insert into a 
select left(group_concat(x separator ', '),10), 
       count(*) 
 from b;
```

This will trim the `GROUP_CONCAT` result for you.

You temporarily can set the `group_concat_max_len` if you need to, then set it back.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I don't want to increase group_concat_max_len.

Comment: So, you're asking: I want to drive to New York City. My car has a flat tire. I don't want to pump it up. So, what's the best route to New York when I'm driving on a rim?  Seriously, if you want to use `GROUP_CONCAT` you're going to have to be willing to use it correctly.

Comment: group_concat result could be greater than 4096. There is no way to tell that is why I asked the question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know MySQL very well, nor if there is a good reason to do this in the first place, but you could create a running total length, and limit the `GROUP_CONCAT()` to where that length is under a certain max, you'll still need to set your `group_concat_max_len` high enough to handle the longest single value (or utilize `CASE` logic to substring them to be under the max length you desire.

Something like this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(GROUP_CONCAT(col1 separator ', '),1,10)
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM (SELECT col1
                  ,@lentot := COALESCE(@lentot,0) + CHAR_LENGTH(col1) AS lentot
            FROM Table1
            )sub
      WHERE lentot < 25
     )sub2
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e756d/34/0)

I don't know if it's SQL Fiddle being quirky or if there's a problem with the logic, but sometimes when running I get no output.  Not big on MySQL so could definitely be me missing something.  It doesn't seem like it should require 2 subqueries but filtering didn't work as expected unless it was nested like that.

Comment: Having a few issues with SQL Fiddle right now, will be back up shortly

Answer (score 0):

Actually, a better way is to use DISTINCT.
I had a situation to add new two fields into existing stored procedure, in a way that a value for that new fields had been obtained by a LEFT JOIN, and because it may have contained a NULL value, a single "concat" value was multiplicated for some cases more than a 100 times.
Because, a group with that new field value contained many NULL values, GROUP_CONCAT exceeded  maximum value (in my case 16384).